# Is there a macro that expands to return without parentheses?

Tags: c, c-preprocessor, parentheses

I want to use a macro like this

```
#define  Return(x)   {call_my_function(); return (x);}
```

is there any way to use or declare a macro without parentheses, so I can use it like a real return call and not a function? For example:

```
BOOL my_func() {
    code....
    Return FALSE;
}
```

Comment: How about `#define Return call_myfunction(); return`?

Comment: @KerrekSB ah you beat it to me :)

Comment: @KerrekSB - This won't work with `if (someCondition()) Return FALSE;`

Comment: IMHO - Avoid macros and `#define` except for simple stuff. I guess that is why C++ has tried to remove them as much as possible from the language. Anyway just bear in mind that it is a simple replacement (no type checking, no scope, nowt). Just a simple search and replace.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something horrific as

```
#define  Return for (call_my_function(); ;) return
```

**Edit:** Changed to Daniel's version for the nice smiley that makes. And Jim's idea of "overloading" `return` directly is valid and even more horrific ;)

Comment: +1 For a valid solution. That's a nice riff on the usual `#define foo do { stuff; } while(0)` to avoid scope problems.

Comment: I would say deliciously horrific, compared to the other answers which are only horrific...

Comment: +1 Or alternately, `#define Return for (call_my_function();;) return`, which doesn't need the comma operator.

Comment: I can actually think of many times -- including something I'm in the middle of right now -- when I could have used `#define return while(somedebugging(), 1) return` ... note that this is **not** a recursive macro!

Answer (score 2):

You can do some trickery (although it's strongly discouraged):

```
#define Return call_my_function(); return
```

Then use it like this:

```
Return false;
```

this will expand to

```
call_my_function; return false;
```

Edit: see the two comments on this question as examples to understand why I discouraged this use.

Comment: That is assuming that `call_my_function` is in itself not a `#define` Otherwise the braces may have an effect.

Comment: @EdHeal why do you think I strongly discouraged its use? :)

Comment: @mouviciel same applies to your comment.

Comment: That's like buying some scissors then complaining about they not being able to cut 0.25" steel...

Comment: H2CO3 - See @mouviciel example. There is quite a few examples when you start to remove scoping.

Comment: Jens Gustedt's answer doesn't have the scope problems.

Answer (score 1):

Consider

```
#define  Return(x)   {call_my_function(); return (x);} 
if (1) Return (0);
```

Woule expand to

```
if (1) {call_my_function(); return (1);}
```

And some people have suggested that you can use summat like

```
#define Return call_my_function(); return
```

now

```
if (1) Return;
```

Would expand to

```
if (1) call_my_function();
return;
```

Slightly different intention.

Answer (score 0):

Remove the { and } from the define.

In a macro the exact characters are used to substitute (except for the x which also is substituted).